# zip and unzip string with Deflate

Tags: c#, .net, deflatestream

I need to zip and unzip string

Here is code:

```
public static byte[] ZipStr(String str)
{
    using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
    using (DeflateStream gzip = new DeflateStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress))
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(gzip))
       {
                writer.Write(str);
                return output.ToArray();
       }
}
```

and

```
public static string UnZipStr(byte[] input)
{
    using (MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(input))
    using (DeflateStream gzip = new DeflateStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(gzip))
       {
        reader.ReadToEnd();
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inputStream.ToArray());
       }
}
```

It seems that there is error in UnZipStr method. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Are you getting a compiler error, or an exception, or what? Can you provide more details about the "error" please?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are two separate problems. First of all, in `ZipStr` you need to flush or close the `StreamWriter` and close the `DeflateStream` before reading from the `MemoryStream`.

Secondly, in `UnZipStr`, you're constructing your result string from the compressed bytes in `inputStream`. You should be returning the result of `reader.ReadToEnd()` instead.

It would also be a good idea to specify the string encoding in the `StreamWriter` and  `StreamReader` constructors.

Try the following code instead:

```
public static byte[] ZipStr(String str)
{
    using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (DeflateStream gzip = 
          new DeflateStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = 
              new StreamWriter(gzip, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                writer.Write(str);           
            }
        }

        return output.ToArray();
    }
}

public static string UnZipStr(byte[] input)
{
    using (MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(input))
    {
        using (DeflateStream gzip = 
          new DeflateStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = 
              new StreamReader(gzip, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mikhail There was a problem with `ZipStr` too. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @PhilRoss Thanks a lot, But I have a question.
How to do this multithreaded? Using TPL?